# finding repeated substring in k length in a string using function

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, substring

I just started using function and I'm trying to build one that's find a repeated substring that is length is at least k and returns the results into tuple that contains a dict.
the keys needs to be the substring and the value is how many times it was repeated, and then add to the tuple the length of the substring.

I just started but I didnt really knew how to continue but this is what I tried to do:

```
def longest_repeat(string, K)
    longest = {} , 
    if isinstance(K, int) and isinstance(string, str)
       for sub_str in string:
          if sub_str >= K:
             longest[0][sub_seq] = DNA_seq_slic = []
a=0
b=k
for nuc in range(len(DNA_seq)-k+1):
    DNA_seq_slic.append(DNA_seq[a:b]) 
    a +=1
    b +=1  
    
import collections
for sub_seq in DNA_seq_slic:
    repeated = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(DNA_seq_slic).items() if count > 1]
repeated_subseq_dict = dict(zip(repeated,[0 for x in range(0,len(repeated))]))
for key in repeated_subseq_dict:
    repeated_subseq_dict[key] = DNA_seq_slic.count(key)
return(repeated_subseq_dict)
```

Im sorry if its a little bit messed up, I didnt really had direction and I tried to use other function I built to solve this and it didnt really worked. I can clarify more if needed.
the output should be something like this:

```
longest_repeated("ATAATACATAATA", 5)
 output: longest = {ATAATA: 2} , 6
```

Really appreciate any kind of help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output?

Comment: longest_repeated("ATAATACATAATA", 5)
 output: longest = {ATAATA: 2} , 6
thanks for appointing that

Comment: Regular expressions (regex) is exactly here for that purpose: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `re` module:

```
import re


def longest_repeated(s, k):
    m = re.findall(f"(.{{{k},}})(?=.*\\1)", s)
    if m:
        mx = max(m, key=len)
        return {mx: s.count(mx)}, len(mx)
```

---

Some tests:

```
print(longest_repeated("ATAATACATAATA", 5))
({'ATAATA': 2}, 6)

print(longest_repeated("XXXXXATAATACATAATAXXXXX", 5))
({'ATAATA': 2}, 6)
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont really know how to use the re modules, but that worked perfect.
can you maybe explain this - m = re.findall(f"(.{{{k},}})(?=.*\\1)", s)
didnt really understood what its saying